# Laravel Nova TinyMCE - Class "Murdercode\TinymceEditor\TinymceEditor" not found

Tags: laravel, tinymce, laravel-nova

I have source code like that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlDzY.png)

**OUTPUT in Notif**

`Class "Murdercode\TinymceEditor\TinymceEditor" not found`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQJJD.png)

I want to upload image to text editor with TinyMCE Laravel Nova